# Using a Case statement to change the value of a cell

Tags: sql, case

Can anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong here? When I try to run it, I get the following error message, "ORA-00937: not a single-group group function".

```
SELECT o.order_number, o.order_date, ol.line_number, ol.line_type, ol.sku, 
  CASE WHEN ol.line_type = 'shipping' THEN 'Shipping Charges' 
       WHEN ol.line_type = 'tax' THEN 'Tax Charges' 
       ELSE p.title 
       END AS price,
ROUND(ol.price,2) AS Price, ol.quantity, SUM(ol.price * ol.quantity) AS total_price
FROM hr.bc_orders o
INNER JOIN hr.bc_orderlines ol ON o.order_number = ol.order_number
LEFT JOIN hr.bc_products p ON ol.sku = p.sku
WHERE o.order_number = 'o21010469' 
ORDER BY ol.line_number;
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Where is your GROUP BY clause?

Comment: When I use the suggested fix it gives me this as my GROUP BY:

Comment: GROUP BY o.order_number, o.order_date, ol.line_number, ol.line_type, ol.sku, CASE, ROUND(ol.price,2), ol.quantity

Comment: Except it still doesn't run.

Comment: What is the new error?

Comment: ORA-00904: "CASE": invalid identifier

Comment: And I think you missed p.title in group by!

Comment: Now I put in GROUP BY o.order_number, o.order_date, ol.line_number, ol.line_type, ol.sku, CASE p.title, ROUND(ol.price,2), ol.quantity and now I get this error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to group by all the non-aggregating columns:

```
SELECT o.order_number, o.order_date, ol.line_number, ol.line_type, ol.sku, 
  CASE WHEN ol.line_type = 'shipping' THEN 'Shipping Charges' 
       WHEN ol.line_type = 'tax' THEN 'Tax Charges' 
       ELSE p.title 
       END AS price,
ROUND(ol.price,2) AS Price, ol.quantity, SUM(ol.price * ol.quantity) AS total_price
FROM hr.bc_orders o
INNER JOIN hr.bc_orderlines ol ON o.order_number = ol.order_number
LEFT JOIN hr.bc_products p ON ol.sku = p.sku
WHERE o.order_number = 'o21010469'
GROUP BY o.order_number, o.order_date, ol.line_number, ol.line_type, ol.sku, 
  CASE WHEN ol.line_type = 'shipping' THEN 'Shipping Charges' 
       WHEN ol.line_type = 'tax' THEN 'Tax Charges' 
       ELSE p.title 
       END,
ROUND(ol.price,2), ol.quantity 
ORDER BY ol.line_number;
```

I also note you have *two* columns called "price" (the case and the round both share the same alias "price").